# Rails: how to create a list with conditional links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on a RAILS application where I create a view which lists all available resources of a given model `species.rb`.

The view partial is:

```
<% i= @s
for species in @species %>
    <%= species.name %>, <%= species.author.surname %> <%= species.author.initial_name %>
<%  i -= 1
    end %>
```

Some of the resources `species` have an related article, others have only the name. I would like to loop through the partial and add a link only to the entries which have an associated article.

Something like: add link if `species.article` is present else just put `species.name` without link + loop through it for all entries.

How can I do this?

UPDATE:

Thanks to @jvillian and @fool-dev I was able to progress. In my case I wanted to add a link if the resource has a description in a description row of its table.

```
<% @species.each do |species| %>
    <div class="entry">
        <p><i><%= link_to_if(species.txtlandscape.present?, "#{species.name}, #{species.author.surname}, #{species.author.initial_name}. 2014", :controller => 'projects', :action => 'show', :id => species) %></i></p>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Now that a link is added I was wondering if it can be used to load a partial to a target such as in, where ArticleRequest is a JS function I have:

```
<% @ species.each do | species | %>
    <div id="species-<%= species.id %>" class="species-entry">
        <a onClick="ArticleRequest('/species/show/<%= species.id %>', 'species-<%= species.id %>');">
            <p><%= species.name %></p>
        </a>
    </div>
<% end  %>
```

Until I find a way to do this with `link_to_if`, I will use something like:

```
<% for species in @species %>
    <% if species.txtlandscape.present? %>
        <a onClick="ArticleRequest('/species/show/<%= species.id %>', 'species-<%= species.id %>');">
            <p><%= species.name %>, <%= species.author.surname %> <%= species.author.initial_name %></p>
        </a>
    <% else %>
        <p><%= species.name %>, <%= species.author.surname %> <%= species.author.initial_name %></p>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What is that `i = @s` and `i -= 1` business all about? Also, you might want to look into [link_to_if](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to_if), although I'm not super-clear what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: I have a model which lists articles on species. Some entries in the related database have only the name, others have a whole article. I would like to create a complete index for the species model with all species listed in a list. Then I would like to add links to the list entries which have a dedicated article to show. Sorry, but it is much simpler than I am able to explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this, see the below

```
<% for species in @species %>
    <% if species.article.present? %> #=> I thin it will be articles because table name is articles, anyway, you know better
        <%= link_to species.name, link_path(species.article) %>, #=> on the link_path it will be your proper link just replace this
    <% else %>
        <%= species.name %>, 
    <% end %>

    <%= species.author.surname %> <%= species.author.initial_name %>
<% end %>
```

You can do this with Rails `each` method like below

```
<% @species.each do |species| %>
    <% if species.article.present? %> #=> I thin it will be articles because table name is articles, anyway, you know better
        <%= link_to species.name, link_path(species.article) %>, #=> on the link_path it will be your proper link just replace this
    <% else %>
        <%= species.name %>, 
    <% end %>

    <%= species.author.surname %> <%= species.author.initial_name %>
<% end %>
```

Or you can use [`link_to_if`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to_if) it is also most easier to understand

```
<% @species.each do |species| %>
    <%= link_to_if(species.article.present?, "#{species.name},", link_path(species.article)) %>

    <%= species.author.surname %> <%= species.author.initial_name %>
<% end %>
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thank you too for your answer. I was implementing the link_to_if and it works, but I need to add a target through an ID. What I am currently working on and which generates a proper list is: `<%= link_to_if(species.txtlandscape.present?, "#{species.name}, #{species.author.surname}, #{species.author.initial_name}. 2014", :controller => 'projects',
  :action => 'show', :id => species) %>` When table species has txtlandscape row add show partial.

Comment: It will be `species.id` or what you need

Answer (score 3):

According to the [docs](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to_if), it seems you should be able to do:

```
<% @species.each do |specie| %>
  <%= link_to_if(specie.article, specie.name, specie_article_path(specie.article)) %>
<% end  %>
```

I made the path name up, you'll have to make that match your actual routes.

BTW, this:

```
for species in @species
```

Is super non-idiomatic.

Comment: Thank you jvillian. I will try it tomorrow morning and report back. The link_to_if sounds promising. I was not aware of it.